# Text area values exploded and submitted to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, explode

```
if(isset($_POST['usersadded'])){    
$value = $_POST['usersadded'];
$lines = explode("\n", $value);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Users_$support (Users) VALUES ('$line')");
};
```

I have a valid connection to the database already, so it's not that that's wrong. But it never submits anything :(

$support is a number, e.g. 19.

Comment: Firstly you have a huge [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) hole in your code. Secondly, try exploding by `\r\n` instead, your code will end up with literal carriage returns in the query string and it may be this that MySQL doesn't like.

Comment: `var_dump($lines);` to see what's inside and add `or die(mysql_error());` after your query. I assume that this script is for fast inserting during development process but if I am mistaken and it's part of project that will be released, I agree with @DaveRandom about SQL injection.

Comment: Oh. I tend to code it, then secure it but I didn't notice. Thanks for pointing out. I suppose I can use a mysql_real_escape_string? 
I am not sure I get what you mean with what the MySQL doesn't like.

Comment: @Christian Data from a `<textarea>` is always `\r\n` seperated, but you are only splitting by `\n` so the `\r`s will be left in the string, and appear literally in the query. You should either split by `\r\n` or pass the data through `trim()` before you use it in the query, or both.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep it in mind!! I learned something new. Yays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would always suggest using this SQL syntax when inserting something with PHP variables inside.

```
mysql_query("
INSERT INTO
    `table_name`
SET
    `field` = '" . $field_variable . "'
");
```

The error might appear when you don't phrase your PHP variables correctly inside the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Users_$support (Users) VALUES (\"'\".$line.\"'\")");
```